# Can I get a photograph kissing my husband?

Tags: halal-haram, husband-wife, photos

I am married for about a month now and I have a very loving husband. We live abroad our country and we have a big house. In our country kissing in public is normal and there are many photographers who make beautiful picture of kissing couple.

Is it permissible for me and my husband to kiss in public and frame it?

I thought it was haram because we would kiss in front of the photographer who makes our picture and when we will frame it the man in the shop will also see the picture.

Answer (score -2):

It is permissible for you to kiss your husband in public because also

> Ibn Umar, one of the best companions of prophet Muhammad, once kissed a slave girl in public and no one of the companions said a word about it.
>   <sub>[Quora](https://www.quora.com/Can-a-Muslim-married-couple-kiss-in-public)</sub>

But, you and your bus ran should not kiss in public where other people can see you as you mentioned ...

> ... or in a place where it is most likely that other people may see them; because bashfulness in one of the traits of faith, as reported from the Prophet  sallallaahu  `alayhi  wa  sallam ( may  God exalt his mention ) by Al-Bukhari and Muslim  may  God  have  mercy  upon  them. Therefore, one should observe the Islamic etiquette when enjoying his wife.
>   <sub>[IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=91996)</sub>

But, you must know one thing, that it is not permissible for you to make a picture of you to because God’s Messenger (ﷺ) said:

> ”Whoever makes a picture will be punished by God till he puts life in it, and he will never be able to put life in it.”

However not all picture making is sin. Ibn `Abbas said to a man whose profession was picture making that:

> ”If you insist on making pictures I advise you to make pictures of trees and any other unanimated objects.”

I almost forgot to tell you that prophet Muhammad also said:

> ”Angels of mercy do not enter a house that have animated images or dog”

And if you really have to make an animated object then, you must have the following intentions which are accepted by God:

1. Image for identity card
2. Driving license
3. Picture for finding the criminal
4. Animated image for educational purposes

If you have these intentions that I mentioned you in the list, then it is ok and there’s no sin upon you.

> Abu Hurayrah (may God be pleased with him) reported that the Prophet (peace and blessings of God be upon him) said: "God, may He be exalted, says: 'Who does more wrong than the one who tries to create something like My creation? Let him create a grain of wheat or a kernel of corn.'" **(Reported by al-Bukhaari, see Fath al-Baari, 10/385).**

God Almighty Says:

> ”O you who believe! Let your slaves and slave‑girls, and those among you who have not come to the age of puberty ask your permission (before they come to your presence) on three occasions: before Fajr (morning) Salaah (prayer), and while you put off your clothes for the noonday (rest), and after the ‘Isha’ (night) Salaah (prayer). (These) three times are of privacy for you; other than these times there is no sin on you or on them to move about, attending to each other.”

Thus God  makes clear the Ayaat (the Verses of this Qur’aan, showing proofs for the legal aspects of permission for visits) to you. And God is All‑Knowing, All‑Wise.

So what do we learn in here is that people should ask your permission so that they can see how you kiss but if they don’t, then you’re not allowed to do that in front of others as per the verse of the Hadith above I mentioned.

**CONCLUSION:** It is permissible for you to kiss your husband in public as long as no one see you, and if they do, then it will become forbidden for you to do that and it is not permissible for you to make a photo of you.

---

**References:**

1. http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=91996
2. https://islamqa.info/en/72220
3. https://www.quora.com/Can-a-Muslim-married-couple-kiss-in-public
4. https://islamqa.info/en/365
5. https://islamqa.info/en/31773

Comment: Why have I got a downvote?

Comment: I added quotations to give credit to their authors.  There's other content which is "borrowed" in this answer, but I couldn't be sure of the source.  You probably got a downvote because this looks like someone took a bunch of random webpages, chopped them apart, and stitched them together like Frankenstein.

Comment: The quote from quora does not mention any source, or even the exact wording and circumstance of the event. I hope you realize that it is a forum and on the internet anyone can claim anything and without verifiable evidence its meaningless, you can't deriving a ruling from some random and anonymous person's claim. Also your first and second sentence contradict each other, "in-public" by definition means that people can see you.

Comment: Also, a photograph is different from a drawn image. There are various opinions on photography among the jurists, and a sizable portion consider them permissible by analogy with the reflection formed in a mirror or water. Framing and hanging one is another matter.